# How to word wrap the legend text for a donut chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a donut chart with a legend.

Problem is that the text of the legend is too long and overflows the size of the container.

How do I carry out a word wrap so that the text continues on the next line?

I tried setting the `word-wrap: break-word` property but it did not work.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't word-wrap SVG.

Comment: It can be done using foreignObject - http://tributary.io/inlet/5320723

Answer (score 1):

As @cuckovic stated, you can use the `<foreignObject>` to word wrap. An example of this would be:

```
<svg width="400px" height="300px">
.
.
    <foreignObject width="100" height="50">
        <p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap.</p>
    </foreignObject>
.
.
</svg>
```

The example given was taken from the Mozilla Developer's site at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject